# Apply a function n times on a starting value

Tags: clojure

Basically I want to apply f on x for n times and I am only interested in the result. Is there any better way than `(nth (iterate f x) n)`?

Comment: That's already pretty succinct and readable. Unless you're golfing, I don't think you'll get much better than that. If you think it's too much, you can always tuck it away in a function.

Comment: It happens to be quite often that I am only interested in the result of iterate. Just wondering if there is already a more expressive way built-in I am overseeing, something like `(dotimes n x body)`

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd just start your own library, and stick a shortcut function in there. I can't see a better "raw" way of expressing this. "The nth iteration of f over x" already reads pretty nice.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well, it's *almost* nice, but `nth` takes its arguments in the "wrong" order and always ends up awkward to read. If you want something that reads like English (and, importantly, puts `nth` near `n`), you can do something like `(-> (iterate f x) (nth n))`: "iterate f over x n times".

Comment: @amalloy Maybe a little better. I try to avoid threading a single form though. I've found it *usually* hinders readability. This may be an exception. Personal opinion though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You may be interested in [an answer I wrote some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12716708/625403), with some opinions about good style in the use of `->`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as the commenters said, your solution is already ok. 
another option is to use `comp`, like this maybe:

```
user> (defn n-times [n f]
        (apply comp (repeat n f)))
#'user/n-times

user> ((n-times 10 inc) 1)
;;=> 11
```

Still I can't really say if it is better then yours in any aspect.
Maybe a bit more functional[ish]